# Current fed resonant Royer converter with switching regulator

Tags: switching-regulator, resonant-converter

In Linear Technology's Application Note 118 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN118fb.pdf there is the following picture of a current fed resonant Royer converter. Why is the 1N5817 there? (provides L1's current path when the transistor in LT1534 on COL pin turns off?). And why is it connected to +5V, could this voltage be higher or lower? I find it a bit hard to integrate in my mind the functioning of the LT1534 and the Royer converter.

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1534fa.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why is the 1N5817 there?*

When the COL pin activates (open collector output) it will draw in current and route it to PGND. When COL deactivates, there still must be a path for the stored energy in L1 to flow without creating a serious over-voltage situation hence, the 1N5817 provides that return path to 5 volts.

> *And why is it connected to +5V*

The voltage seen on the COL output (due to the diode feeding the 5 volts rail) will be roughly a square wave with a peak of about 5.5 volts and a trough of 0 volts. This is sufficient to turn off and on the two transistors directly above it.

> *could this voltage be higher or lower?*

If the two transistors above the diode were fed from a higher or lower supply voltage then it would need to connect to that voltage to be most effective.